# Python multidimensional array

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm a bit of a beginner in Python, but I think I have a simple question. I am using image processing to detect lines in an image

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,50,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
```

lines.shape is (151, 1, 4) meaning that I've detected 151 lines, and has 4 parameters x1, y1, x2, y2.

What I want to do is add another factor to lines, called slope, thus increasing lines.shape to (151, 1, 5). I know I can concatenate an empty array of zeros at the end of lines, but how do I make it so I can call it in a for loop or the like?

For example I want to be able to say

```
for slope in lines
   #do stuff
```

Comment: Does `slope` need to be part of the same array?  Can't it just be another array? In your 'loop', what is `#do stuff`?  Does it operate on single numbers or on an array of 151 values?

Comment: `for x in lines:` iterates on the 1st dimension of the array.  `lines[:,:,-1]` gives the last 'column' of the array (the 'slope' column after concatenation).

Comment: Ultimately, I want to take all the lines with (roughly) the same slope and position, and delete them until there is one line in each position. (I should only find 4 lines in my picture, but houghlinesp finds 151, most of which are close or on top of one another). So instead of having to delete an element from slope and from lines, I could just delete from lines.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `HoughLinesP` function returns a numpy array of type `int32`. I stayed up past my bedtime to figure this out, though, so I'm going to post it anyways. I just multiplied the slopes by 1000 and put them in the array like that. Hopefully, it's still useful to you.

```
slopes = []
for row in lines:
    slopes.append((row[0][1] - row[0][3]) / float(row[0][0] - row[0][2]) * 1000)

new_column = []
for slope in slopes:
    new_column.append([slope])

new_array = np.insert(lines, 4, new_column, axis=2)

print lines
print
print new_array
```

Sample output:

```
[[[14 66 24 66]]

 [[37 23 54 56]]

 [[ 7 62 28 21]]

 [[70 61 81 61]]

 [[24 64 42 64]]]

[[[   14    66    24    66     0]]

 [[   37    23    54    56  1941]]

 [[    7    62    28    21 -1952]]

 [[   70    61    81    61     0]]

 [[   24    64    42    64     0]]]
```

Edit: Better (and full) code with same output

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('cmake_logo-main.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,50,3,10)

def slope(xy):
    return (xy[1] - xy[3]) / float(xy[0] - xy[2]) * 1000
new_column = [[slope(row[0])] for row in lines]
new_array = np.insert(lines, 4, new_column, axis=2)

print lines
print
print new_array
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, here's my guess as to what you should do:

```
lines = np.squeeze(lines) 
# remove the unneeded middle dim, a convenience, but not required
slope = <some calculation> # expect (151,) array of floats
mask = np.ones((151,),dtype=bool) # boolean mask
<assign False to mask for all lines you want to delete>
<alt start with False, and set True to keepers>
lines = lines[mask]
slope = lines[mask]
```

Alternatively you could extend `lines` with `np.hstack([lines, np.zeros((151,1))])` (or concatenate on axis 1).  But if as `Jason` thinks, `lines` is `dtype` `int`, and `slope` must be `float`, that won't work.  You'd have to use his scaling solution.

You could also use a structured array to combine the ints and float columns into one array.  Why do that if it is just as easy to keep `slope` as separate variable?